# How to force NSD Android to use local network, not mobile one

Tags: android

I am connected to two networks, one is wifi without internet and the other is mobile data.  My device finds other devices in the local network (wifi), but when it tries to connect, there is a timeout because it is trying to connect to mobile data.  How can I force connection to the local network?

Comment: What does "NSD" stand for?

Comment: @Egor Network Service Discovery https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd